# Is a subspace of a product space also a product space?

Tags: product-space

Suppose $V$ is a product space of connected and separable spaces $V_1,...,V_n$. Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ with the subspace topology. Is $W$ then a product space of subsets of $V_1,...,V_n$?

My attempt: It is not a product space of subsets of $V_i$. Is $V=(\{a,b\}\times\{c,d\},\tau)$ with $\tau$ the product topology and $W=(\{(a,c),(b,d)\},\tau_W)$ with $\tau_W$ the subspace topology a suitable counterexample?

Comment: What exactly do you mean that it is not a product space? Is $W\times \{*\}$ considered a product space?

Comment: ah nice! That already clarifies a lot. I guess what I mean is that it is not a product space of subsets of $V_1,...,V_n$. Will edit the question accordingly!

Comment: Note that your question is not really related to the topology. Your $W$ is definitely a counterexample, no matter what the topology is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could literally just write down every possible product of two subspaces, and see if any of them turn out to be $W$.